# I would like to make this responsive timeline to have 6 steps

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need 6 steps. I tried for hours, I just can't make it work. I'm pretty sure it's not that hard for someone more experienced. I've had several forks but all are dead end.
Could you help me out please?

http://codepen.io/kjohnson/pen/azBvaE

HTML:

```
 <section id="Steps" class="steps-section">

<h2 class="steps-header">
  Responsive Semantic Timeline
</h2>

<div class="steps-timeline">

  <div class="steps-one">
    <img class="steps-img" src="http://placehold.it/50/3498DB/FFFFFF" alt="" />
    <h3 class="steps-name">
      Semantic
    </h3>
    <p class="steps-description">
      The timeline is created using negative margins and a top border.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="steps-two">
    <img class="steps-img" src="http://placehold.it/50/3498DB/FFFFFF" alt="" />
    <h3 class="steps-name">
      Relative
    </h3>
    <p class="steps-description">
       All elements are positioned realtive to the parent. No absolute positioning.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="steps-three">
    <img class="steps-img" src="http://placehold.it/50/3498DB/FFFFFF" alt="" />
    <h3 class="steps-name">
      Contained
    </h3>
    <p class="steps-description">
       The timeline does not extend past the first and last elements.
    </p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.steps-timeline -->
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic);
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: lato;
}

.section-header, .steps-header, .steps-name {
  color: #3498DB;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.steps-header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.steps-timeline {
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .steps-timeline {
    border-left: 2px solid #3498DB;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .steps-timeline {
    border-top: 2px solid #3498DB;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 16.65%;
    margin-right: 16.65%;
  }
}
.steps-timeline:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.steps-one,
.steps-two,
.steps-three {
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .steps-one,
  .steps-two,
  .steps-three {
    margin-left: -25px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .steps-one,
  .steps-two,
  .steps-three {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .steps-one,
  .steps-two {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .steps-one {
    margin-left: -16.65%;
    margin-right: 16.65%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .steps-three {
    margin-bottom: -100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .steps-three {
    margin-left: 16.65%;
    margin-right: -16.65%;
  }
}

.steps-img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .steps-img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.steps-name,
.steps-description {
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .steps-name {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.steps-description {
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .steps-description {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? What do you mean by 6 steps? maybe demonstrate the desired outcome? thank you

Comment: Check the codepen, I think its quite obvious. It has 3 steps currently, and they are equally far from each other. I want 6. 6 circles, 6 headings, 6 paragraphs, equally far from each other on the line. It "collapses" into a vertical timeline after resizing the window.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want something like this?

http://codepen.io/adamk22/pen/LGQQKz

```
$outline-width: 0;
$break-point: 500px;

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic);

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  font-family: lato;
}

$gray-base:     #999999;
$brand-primary: #3498DB; //Zen Blue

.section-header {
  color: $brand-primary;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}


.steps-header {
  @extend .section-header;
  margin-bottom: 20px;  
  text-align: center;
}
.steps-timeline {
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(red, $outline-width);

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    border-left: 2px solid $brand-primary;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    border-top: 2px solid $brand-primary;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
  }

  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
.steps-one,
.steps-two,
.steps-three,
.steps-four,
.steps-five,
.steps-six{
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(green, $outline-width);

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    margin-left: -25px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    float: left;
    width: 12%;  
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
.steps-one,
.steps-two,
.steps-three,
.steps-four,
.steps-five,
.steps-six{
  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
.steps-one {
  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-left: -8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
  }
}
.steps-two {
    @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-right: 8%;
  }
}
.steps-three {
  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-right: 8%;
  }
}

.steps-four {
    @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-right: 8%;
  }
}

.steps-five {
}

.steps-six {
    @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    margin-bottom: -100%;
  }
    @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: -8%;
  }

}

.steps-img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%; 

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.steps-name,
.steps-description {
  margin: 0;
}
.steps-name {
  @extend .section-header;

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.steps-description {
  overflow: hidden;

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Most of the changes require you to change the CSS, especially the media queries as you can see in the pen.

Comment: I can't believe you did this flawlessly in a few minutes, when I spent hours on it. You are my hero. Thank you very much.

Comment: I recently came back to play around with this since I want to fully understand everything behind it. I've now got a decent grasp of it, but I have a problem with the timeline on small screen sizes if I change the values to fit various number of steps.  Could you help me out, why is the left border too long on small screen sizes? I can't seem to fix it properly, only in some hacky, "treating only the symptoms" way. Thanks
http://codepen.io/simii/pen/mVNawx/

Comment: If you turn on a background on the steps-timeline class you'll notice that the timeline border's length depends on the amount of content placed in that div. If you decrease the screensize, you'll notice that the extra long border is caused by the text. So a way to fix this is to use a negative margin on the :last-child of the class steps-description with a media query. It's not the ideal fix, but then again, it's not the ideal way to make a timeline imo :-) See: http://codepen.io/adamk22/pen/EKYLMN?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks :) Now I see how its done. Thank you.

Well, I realize this is not the best way to do a timeline, I've been looking for ways to create a timeline like this, which collapses similar to this but I didn't find anything better. I'm not in a state yet where I can come up with something better either unfortunately.  
Thank you again